# Monitor cashdrawer opened or not using EPSON printer in C#

Tags: c#, epson, opos

We have Point of sale application.
We don't want to start the billing while the cash-drawer is open.

I saw EPSON is having the "Auto Status Back" function.
I have installed the "OPOS for dotnet" from the EPSON website.

It does open the cash drawer and prints to the printer.
But when it comes to "cash-drawer open/close status", it is always returning false.
The sample C# application is provided by EPSON, has `OnStatusUpdateEvent` event.
It is firing when I open the printer cover, power on/off. But not firing when the cash-drawer is open/close.

I have tried this sample code using [ESC-POS](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET).
Here also am getting `"IsCashDrawerOpen = false"` always.

```json
{
   "IsWaitingForOnlineRecovery":false,
   "IsPaperCurrentlyFeeding":false,
   "IsPaperFeedButtonPushed":false,
   "IsPrinterOnline":true,
   "IsCashDrawerOpen":false,
   "IsCoverOpen":false,
   "IsPaperLow":false,
   "IsPaperOut":false,
   "IsInErrorState":false,
   "DidRecoverableErrorOccur":false,
   "DidUnrecoverableErrorOccur":false,
   "DidAutocutterErrorOccur":false,
   "DidRecoverableNonAutocutterErrorOccur":false,
   "DeviceConnectionTimeout":false
}
```

The printer model is EPSON TM-T82(Connected Via USB).
The cash-drawer is connected via an RJ11 cable connected to the printer.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Auto Status Back" function is automatically processed inside the OPOS or POS for.NET service object and is not visible to the application.

For "It is firing when I open the printer cover, power on/off.", It is possible that PowerState Online/Offline is notified instead of Open/Close of the CashDrawer.
Please check the value of the status property of StatusUpdateEventArgs.

For "But not firing when the cashdrawer is open/close.", The open state sensor of the CashDrawer may not exist, is not connected, or may be broken. Or the setting by Setup POS (Which is Open state, LOW or HIGH?) May be different.

Are the CashDrawer and connection cable EPSON's? If it is from another manufacturer, is it listed in information such as EPSON's confirmed operation list? Please check it.

---

By the way, OPOS and ESC-POS-.NET are separate and independent, and there will be little information that can be complemented by arranging them side by side.

---

You can find the connector wiring diagram on page 68 of the document that you can download from this page.
[TM-T82 (Singapore & India Model) Technical Reference Guide](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_doc&cid=6523&pcat=3&pid=39)
Is it supported and connected?

Or, since the previous page describes the buzzer unit that connects to the drawer kick connector, it may be set to the mode to connect this unit.
Please refer to the setting description starting on page 54 to check.

Comment: Thank you @kunif.
**Please check the value of the status property of StatusUpdateEventArgs.** 
Yes, I have breakpoint and checking the status. The notification works for other operations. If I turnoff the printer, then am getting **PosCommon.StatusPowerOff**. But not firing any notification for drawer Open/Close.

In the "SetupPOS for OPOS", drawer open status is "Low Signal".
I have tried changing both status from low/high, resulting in same output. Am not getting event notification.

Comment: The cashdrawer and printer are brand new one. 
The printer support OPOS. 
[link](https://download.epson-biz.com/epson/epson_public_document.php?name=opos_3.00.pdf)

The cashdrawer is not from EPSON, it is 405 model. I dont know whether it is having sensor or not. Can you suggest any cashdrawer model which support this?

Comment: EPSON in Japan sells such models. [レシートプリンター キャッシュドロアー](https://www.epson.jp/products/receiptprinter/cash/?xadid=nks19_RP_0021&utm_medium=paidsearch&utm_source=Google&utm_campaign=nks_RP&utm_content=nks19_RP_0021) Please contact your country's EPSON Support Desk or your dealer to find out what is supported in your country.

Comment: I have requested my management to buy the cash-drawer that you have suggested (CD-A3336W).  I dont want to change the current memory settings in the printer now. Let me check with EPSON cash-drawer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hello @kunif, I have contacted the local vendor. They given us OPOS enabled printer Bixolon SRP-E300 and cash-drawer from EPOS ECH-410. It support OPOS and it is giving the status BXL_STS_CASHDRAWER_HIGH , BXL_STS_CASHDRAWER_LOW.  I have achieved what I wanted. Thanks.